# how to highlight a specific interval and label it in ggplot with a line on the same graph in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I am trying to add a line for a specific time interval on the same graph. I was successful in adding a point for that interval but not able to plot a line. 
My data set spans over a month and has 2000+ records for the same Point.

I am facing the following problems.

1. I am not able to plot a colored vertical line on the graph at the specific interval(currently where the "red" point is in the below graph)
2. I am not able to label the horizontal line on the graph.
3. TIME on the x-axis is messed up.

I am using the following :

`ggplot(sampledata, aes(x=TIME, y=TEMP)) 
+ geom_line(colour="blue") 
+ geom_point(data=sampledata[sampledata$ISFAILED==1, ], aes(x=TIME, y=TEMP), colour="red", size =5) 
+ geom_hline(yintercept=mean(sampledata$TEMP)) 
+ annotate("text", mean(sampledata$TEMP), mean(sampledata$TEMP), label = "Average Temp of the Point") 
+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(20,60)) 
+ scale_x_datetime(breaks="3 hour")
+ ggtitle("Analysis of the Failed Point") 
+ theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))`

The graph which I am getting after the above code is :

[image]

my data set looks like this:

`POINTs TIME                        ISFAILED    TEMP
Point A 2014-08-01-01.29.21.904990         0    48
Point A 2014-08-01-03.26.13.074337         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-07.53.10.520026         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-04.32.55.003535         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-02.52.45.467612         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-06.46.18.597976         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-07.19.53.073411         0    49
Point A 2014-08-01-05.40.10.461919         0    47
Point A 2014-08-01-00.56.06.125871         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-09.00.30.929944         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-11.13.55.381132         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-17.36.20.011432         0    53
Point A 2014-08-01-15.39.52.437406         0    48
Point A 2014-08-01-16.13.07.448502         0    54
Point A 2014-08-01-16.29.48.596822         0    54
Point A 2014-08-01-07.03.11.885053         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-13.44.01.552165         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-06.29.38.790211         0    49
Point A 2014-08-01-10.39.58.155461         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-08.09.55.884192         0    49
Point A 2014-08-01-09.33.52.323988         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-10.57.19.051928         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-12.53.29.557342         0    49
Point A 2014-08-01-17.03.36.697180         0    54
Point A 2014-08-01-02.02.46.494588         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-02.36.05.328555         0    48
Point A 2014-08-01-04.49.30.035927         0    50
Point A 2014-08-01-11.30.39.280761         0    51
Point A 2014-08-01-11.46.46.207718         0    48
Point A 2014-08-02-11.05.02.353600         0    56
Point A 2014-08-02-09.25.17.728003         0    58
Point A 2014-08-02-03.35.40.512034         0    54
Point A 2014-08-02-06.22.47.452380         0    49
Point A 2014-08-01-19.33.18.048757         0    55
Point A 2014-08-02-01.39.03.352322         0    58
Point A 2014-08-02-04.59.25.138487         0    55
Point A 2014-08-02-07.28.47.747091         1    29
Point A 2014-08-02-02.45.45.520469         0    55
Point A 2014-08-01-23.59.15.588449         0    57
Point A 2014-08-02-05.48.58.214984         0    48
Point A 2014-08-02-19.57.24.112321         0    30
Point A 2014-08-02-09.08.40.053227         0    58
Point A 2014-08-02-04.25.34.167623         0    55`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your partial data set, I first shortened the TIME variable to keep only the year/month/date.

```
sampledata$TIME <- substr(x = sampledata$TIME, start = 1, stop = 10)
```

Borrowing much of your `ggplot2` code, the following inserts a vertical line (which you can relocate as you wish) and labels the horizontal mean line (and, again, you can locate it as as you wish, including using the `vjust` argument).  I angled the TIME axis text so that each day is more visible, but you can also shorten the variable more, reduce the font size, show every other day, etc. for further refinement on the entire data set.

```
ggplot(sampledata, aes(x=TIME, y=TEMP)) + 
  geom_line(colour="blue") + 
  geom_point(data=sampledata[sampledata$ISFAILED==1, ], aes(x=TIME, y=TEMP), colour="red", size =5) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(sampledata$TEMP)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5, color = "red") +
  annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = mean(sampledata$TEMP), label = "Average Temp of the Point") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30))
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for not adding the data set @lawyeR. I have added my data set now. I have 2000+ records for the entire month. Can you please provide me a solution to my 3 problems mentioned above.

> class(sampledata$TIME)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"


> class(sampledata$TEMP)
[1] "numeric"


> class(sampledata$ISFAILED)
[1] "numeric"

Comment: The revised answer should do it, Amrut.  I trust you will consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Still I am not able to label @lawyeR. When I am trying to label it, it is throwing me an error " Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only "........ Regarding TIME on x-axis, I want to plot time intervals rather than date. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I added the data set I used, in case yours is different.  Note that I dropped the first row since it was all the same and read.table(textConnection) objected.  By "time intervals" do you mean "Day 1", "Day 2" etc.?  I have spent much time on this.

Comment: I apologize for taking your much time. By time intervals I meant to say 01:00:00 , 01:30:00, 02:00:00, ...... 23:30:00 ... OR 01:00:00, 02:00:00, .... , 23:00:00.

Comment: Thank you very much @lawyeR

Comment: To me, it looks like @lawyerR has covered the OP's 3 questions, and spent a lot of time on this for you... so I think this should be accepted as an answer.  Even if the x-axis format isn't what your going for, it wasn't made clear in the OP and seems like a pretty minor point.

Comment: @JamesAdamCampbell.  I very much appreciate your comment.  The etiquette on SO is for a question-asker to accept an answer that does the job (notwithstanding further questions).  I spent a lot of time helping Amrut and I do not understand why he has not accepted this much-edited answer.

Comment: @Amrut: how do you respond to the comment of James Adam Campbell?

Comment: I am not an Expert in R as of yet. You guys are experts. I know time is much important to you. But then I am learning, trying out different things, creating own data sets, borrowing some data sets, gain knowledge. Thank you very much for helping me @lawyeR. JamesAdamCampbell and lawyeR , yes I do accept the answer. I apologize for asking more questions. It has worked for me very well. Very much appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to help, Amrut.  You must check the accept answer arrow to accept it so that others who read your question and the answer know that you have accepted it.  Please click on the arrow.